# Leaking conservatory roof

Tags: leak

When the wind comes from a certain direction my conservatory roof leaks. . Is there some substance I could use (similar to putty?) to stop the leak?

Comment: Can you describe the roof structure / materials? Have you located the source of the leak? Where do you intend to place this patch?

Comment: Pretty old fashioned, but it is for a conservatory: Oakum?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oakum